# how to provide a very basic node server to serve a webcomponent for local tests?

Tags: node.js, web-component

I just want to test my webcomponets and I am getting

```
simple-call.js:1 Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Reading around I found several answers to start node but this is exactly what I am doing. There is a significant difference in my case: index.html import a Webcomponent and this may add extra requirements I didn´t find yet.

So my straight question is, how can I start a very simple Web Server to serve the bellow index.html without getting the error mentioned above?

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8082; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;    

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

index.html (just two lines for now)

```
<script type="module" src="./simple-call.js"></script>

<simple-call></simple-call>
```

simple-call.js (a very simple vanilla webcomponet)

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `<input id="inputSimpleRequest"/>`;

class SimpleCall extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {

    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))

    const inputSimpleRequest = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputSimpleRequest');
    const url = 'http://localhost:8081/';

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      inputSimpleRequest.value = data.somephrase; 
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

  }
}

window.customElements.define("simple-call", SimpleCall);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip it around a little:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8888;

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write(JSON.stringify(err, 0, 2));
    }
    else {
      response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write(html);
    }

    response.end();
  });
}).listen(PORT);
```

**UPDATE**: I changed and tested the code above. It does work as long as there is a file named `index.html` otherwise it displays an error page.

I did not test this, but the idea is to re-read the HTML file every time it is requested and not just once.

Or you can use `express` and make it serve up real files based on the URL:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT = 4000;

// The magic happens here
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server is running at:',PORT);
});
```

Then you create a folder called `public` and place your files and sub-folders in there.

**Further Update:**

Here is a slightly better server without express.

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8888;

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  let url = '.'+request.url;
  if (url === './') {
    url += 'index.html';
  }
  console.log(url);
  fs.readFile(url, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write(JSON.stringify(err, 0, 2));
    }
    else {
      response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write(html);
    }

    response.end();
  });
}).listen(PORT);
```

This allows you to access any file in the existing folder structure.

***Be careful though. There is no protection and someone could attempt to load files in paths below the current path. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION***

Comment: Your first suggest didn´t change the error at all. I will try the second

Comment: your second suggestion fixed my issue. In few words, it seems I must use express server instead of native node http server since I want to serve an index.html which imports a webcomponent module.

Comment: I changed the first example and tested it. As long as there is a file named `index.html` then it works fine.

Comment: Your new refactored suggestion without Express Server raised same original error (Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec). When you said it works are you really trying with my index.html? Please take a note that my question is "a simple node server that can work with Webcomponents". Did you you get this idea from my index.html? Did you note it imports a Webcomponent? I don't know the reason but it seems the default http server fails while Express server not

Comment: Ahhhh. You would need to return the correct mime type based on the filename to fix that error. Instead of always returning `{"Content-Type": "text-html"}` it needs to change for your different kind of files. Express does that automatically. Try this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime